# Searching for a value in Excel between worksheets, if found returning value from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one workbook that has two worksheets. I need a function that will take a value from column A in the worksheet_1 and compare it to column D in worksheet_2. If the value is found within column D in worksheet_2, then display the contents of column A in worksheet_2. If not found, display "Not Found".

In worksheet_1, I have the following dataset:

```
     A
1. ABC123
2. DEF234
3. GHI567
4. JKLM123
5. OPQ456
6. RSTU789
```

In worksheet_2, I have the following dataset:

```
    A       D                             
1.  RED     ER4654F- RSTU789 - 54DF56GH
2.  BLUE    132DF- ABC123 - SDFG1665
3.  GREEN   456FD-OPQ456-D564G
4.  PURPLE  7987-DEF234-165416
5.  ORANGE  SDF86- JKLM123 -5DFG6H
```

How would I structure the function in order to properly look up if the values from worksheet_1 exist in workseet_2's column D and display the values from column A?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Okay... here's a new wrinkle to this request. How can I use the MATCH function to search for a match over several columns, such as Column D though Z and if a match is found, return the result of the column it was found in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MATCH function to search Column D in Sheet2 for the item in Column A of Sheet1. For example in cell B1 of Sheet1 you could enter:

```
=MATCH("*"&$A1&"*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0)
```

This will return the line number in Sheet2 Column D where the contents of A1 is found, or #N/A if no match was found. The "*" before and after the search term are wild cards.

You can use the INDEX function to get the contents of Sheet2 Column A. Change cell B1 to:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&$A1&"*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0))
```

This will return the value of Sheet2 Column A that corresponds to the item that was found in Sheet2 Column D, or #N/A if no match was found.

You can use the IFERROR function to show "Not found" when there is no match. Change cell B1 to

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&$A1&"*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0)),"Not Found")
```

The only remaining problem is that using wildcards means you might get a match on just part of the term in Column D (for example "BC12" would be found on row 2). If that isn't what you want, I suggest changing Column D to remove the spaces and add a "-" at the start and end of each item, so row 1 becomes:

```
'-ER4654F-RSTU789-54DF56GH-
```

(the apostrophe tells Excel not to treat this as a calculation). Now you can add a "-" before and after the search term to ensure that you match only the things between the "-" in Column D. The final formula in cell B1 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("*-"&$A1&"-*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0)),"Not Found")
```

Copy this formula to the other cells in Sheet1 Column B.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Very good answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. This worked like a dream and I've been able to use it in many other spreadsheets. This has helped me in so many ways. Again, thanks!